# How to calculate the partial derivative of function within another function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I need someone help to calculate the partial derivative. Following is the question

$$R=\frac{ba^2}{(b+k)^2}-\textrm{Cost}\left(\frac{ba}{b+k}\right)$$

Derivative of the first term has been calculated as following  $$\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\frac{ba^2}{(b+k)^2}=\frac{(b+k)^2a^2-2a^2b(b+k)}{(b+k)^4}=\frac{a^2k-ba^2}{(b+k)^3}$$

Now, what will be the partial derivative of the following (that is the second term of $R$)?
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\textrm{Cost}\left(\frac{ba}{b+k}\right)=?$$

$$\textrm{Cost}(x)={\lambda_2x^2}+{\lambda_1x}-{\lambda_0}$$

Note: here, I need to calculate the partial derivative of the following two cases e.g.,  different values of $x$ variable

1. $$x=a$$
2. $$x=\frac{ba}{b+k}$$

$$\frac{\partial R}{\partial b}=\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left[\frac{ba^2}{(b+k)^2}-\textrm{Cost}\left(\frac{ba}{b+k}\right)\right]=?$$
Please help to me calculate the deravitive in both cases, I will need both solutions.

Comment: Cost is just a polynomial no? Just put in $ba/(b+k)$, regard $\lambda_{0,1,2}, a, k$ as constant and differentiate in respect to $b$(assuming the $\lambda$'s are not a functions for $b$)

Comment: yes, the cost is a polynomial as mentioned above. Kind of quadratic equation. Please further explain

Comment: Instead of writing $Cost (x)=...$ plug in $x$ the value $ba/(b+k)$, this will give you 3 terms to differentiate.

Comment: OK, yes, I did the same way once before, but I unable to reproduce results mentioned in a paper using the above equation. So I was thinking, maybe there will be a mistake in my derivation. But thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Key word: The Chain Rule.

Comment: Yes, Fan Zheng! the answer will be the same whether we calculate derivative as advised by Holo or Dylan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule

$$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial b} = \frac{dC}{dx}\frac{\partial x}{\partial b} $$

where $C$ is the cost function.

You then have

$$ \frac{dC}{dx} = 2\lambda_2x + \lambda_1 $$

and

$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial b} = \frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left(\frac{ab}{b+k}\right) = \frac{ak}{(b+k)^2} $$

Now multiply them and plug in $x$ in terms of $b$

Comment: Thanks, I got the same answer when plugged values in both solutions. For example, solution advised by Holo and you.

Comment: If you're done with the question, be sure to 'tick' the best answer to close it.